# How can I solve/verify the following matrix?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

Given $ZFZ’ = C$, I have the following set of symbolic matrices:

- $Z$ of order $m\times q$
- $Z’$ is the transpose of matrix $Z$ of order $q\times m$
- $F$ of order $q\times q$
- $C$ of order $m\times m$

Note that $m \gg q$.

With that said, I need to solve for $F$ (symbolically).

I tried with the following code, but it says that $F$ is not a valid variable:

```
m = 3;
q = 2;

Z = Array[z, {m, q}];
F = Array[f, {q, q}];
Zt = Transpose[Z];
Cs = Array[c, {m, m}];

sltn = Solve[Z.F.Zt == Cs, F] // Flatten // FullSimplify;
```

Comment: Let this run until it finishes `Z={{z1,z2},{z3,z4},{z5,z6}};F={{f1,f2},{f3,f4}};Zt={{z1,z3,z5},{z2,z4,z6}}; Cs={{c1,c2,c3},{c4,c5,c6},{c7,c8,c9}}; InputForm[Simplify[Reduce[Z.F.Zt==Cs,{f1,f2,f3,f4}]]]` and edit your post to include the output to show us how ugly the result is.

Comment: Others have given good suggestions. I just want to point out that the variable list needs to be a flat list, so in this case it should be `Flatten[F]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the advantage of the fact [pseudoinversion commutes with transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)

```
pZ = PseudoInverse[Z];
pZt = pZ\[Transpose];
```

and noting that:

```
FullSimplify[pZ . (Z . F . Zt) . pZt == F]
(*True*)
```

we can write:

```
sltn = Flatten[pZ . Cs . pZt]
```

I didn't run `FullSimplify` on `sltn` as it was taking a long time since it's rather large and ugly.